# Shell Pipe Implementation single level

Tags: c++, shell

I am writing my shell and this is the piece of code. Can anyone please explain why I am not reaching in the end of following function i.e OUT is not printed.I have read shell related article but they don't seem to help.
commandargs() function returns formatted string i.e removing spaces and storing arguments. My 2 nights are wasted doing debugging only.

### It works fine and output is correct but program execution stops after this function.

```
int shellpipe(char **arg)
{
//  pid_t childpid;
  int status;
  int pfd[2];
  pid_t cpid;
  char c;
  char **p=commandargs(arg[0]);
  char **q=commandargs(arg[1]);
cout<<"q0";//not printed

  if ( pipe(pfd) < 0){
    perror("pipe");
    return 1;
  }

  cpid = fork();

  if( cpid == 0 )
  {
    /* CHILD 1*/
    close(0);
    dup2(pfd[0], 0);
    close(pfd[1]);
    if (execvp(q[0],q)==-1)
            perror("Executing Error");


    exit(0);
  } else if ( cpid > 0){
    /* PARENT */
    close(1);
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[0]);
    if (execvp(p[0],p)==-1)
            perror("Executing Error");
    close(pfd[1]);
    close(1);
    wait(&status);

  }else{
    /* ERROR */
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
  }
  cout<<"Out";//control don't reach here

}
```

Comment: You have `execvp` in both branches. Assuming no error occurs, that's where your program ends.

Comment: There are no errors and output is same as ls|wc

Comment: why does execvp causes termination if it's in both branches?

Comment: `execvp` doesn't cause termination. `execvp` loads another program into the current process, overwriting the old program (i.e. your code). That's why none of your code is still running after exec.

Comment: What might be the solution then? I have hit a wall here

Comment: Fork again. It looks like you want to have 3 processes, `ls`, `wc`, and your own program all running at the same time, so you have to fork twice.

Comment: thanks a lot melpomene. I think now i am on right track because of you!!

Answer (score 0):

"Out" isn't printed because the output stream is already closed. It might also be that the child process never finishes, but this would require a closer look on the argument strings.

Comment: why is q0 not printed 10th line

Comment: @user2397292 It's probably buffered (and the buffer is lost when you `exec` another program).

Comment: Yes as melpomene said you need to flush the output buffer, you can do this by cout << std::endl for example or just call flush on the stream.